# Technical Debt in frontend development

Tags: architecture, documentation, technical-debt

I have recently joined in a new company as a frontend developer and I got access to their current repository which is made in ReactJS. I can see that current team is not very experienced in reactJS and standards. Some examples like

1. not using redux or any state management
2. lots of unused packages
3. Using class based components sometimes and functional components sometimes.
4. Incorrectly using web pack in a CRA project.

I am assuming this must be to meet the deadlines.

How can I make a presentation with the technical debts in current project.
I feel like creating a side project & start porting the current project to a project with good standards like typescript and proper CRA.

Company’s main product is not in frontend but its AI and frontend only serves its ai to clients and I see current frontend’s repository is not that big as well. I estimate 2 developers can port the current project in a time of 2-3 weeks.

I am not experienced in creating presentations for such things.Is there a guide on how I can create and explain that state in which current project is in will have a huge technical debt if it grows in size.

Thanks

Comment: This question seems dangerously close to *"How do I broadcast my opinion and have it recognised?"*, to which the simple answer is *"Never do this - ever."*  Whatever you do almost certainly won't be well-received.   I'd urge a more collaborative approach (preferably after getting up-to-speed to better understand the overall team and organisational context you're working in) by initiating dialogue/discussions with the team on the areas and specific issues where you would like to see improvements, and lead by asking everybody else for *their* opinions before you even think about offering yours.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what "recently joined" means, but you are new to the company. A recent hire coming in and telling people that their project has a lot of technical debt and problems probably won't go over well.

The first thing to do is learn. You are making an assumption that they are introducing this low quality code in order to meet deadlines. Find out if that's true. There are other possible reasons, too. Perhaps they are inexperienced with JavaScript and/or React and don't have the prior knowledge and experience to make good decisions. Perhaps there's apathy about code quality and technical debt. Ask questions about why they aren't using state management libraries, why unused packages are included in the builds, and so on.

Once you understand why, maybe you can start to improve things.

It seems like removing unused packages could be low-hanging fruit and easily accomplished. Maybe not fully, but at least partially. It could also open the door to broader conversations about dependency management and its impact on buildability and security.

Introducing a more standard state management package, if there is a need for it in the project, could also be done. If they have rolled their own implementation, it could create space for conversations about build versus buy or vendor selection.

I would strongly advise against making a presentation, unless you are asked to. I would focus on asking questions and having conversations. If the team is truly inexperienced, make your experience available to the team so they can understand the benefits of other approaches and make informed decisions about how to improve the quality of their software.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is the first time I am in this kind of situation and don’t know how to communicate . When I was joining I was told that the company lacks frontend developers and team is small. Code does look like built in a hurry to complete deadlines, which I saw in team meeting as well. It’s my 2nd day only. I want to best for the company and I want help before it becomes unmanageable. May be it’s better to discuss about best practices and slowly transform whole project into best practices.